# Exceptions in SNS Android App

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging, subscription, amazon-sns

I've integrated AWS SNS API in my Android app. When I opened the app, I got this error log:

```
E/GCMTokenHelper: Unable to register with GCM. MAIN_THREAD
                                                           java.io.IOException: MAIN_THREAD
                                                               at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source)
                                                               at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source)
                                                               at com.amazonaws.mobile.push.GCMTokenHelper.updateGCMToken(GCMTokenHelper.java:79)
                                                               at com.amazonaws.mobile.push.PushManager.registerDevice(PushManager.java:196)
                                                               at com.intap.appme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
10-01 20:54:37.354 4725-4725/com.intap.appme E/PushManager: Push Notifications - FAILED : GCM registration failed : java.io.IOException: MAIN_THREAD
                                                        java.io.IOException: MAIN_THREAD
                                                            at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source)
                                                            at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getToken(Unknown Source)
                                                            at com.amazonaws.mobile.push.GCMTokenHelper.updateGCMToken(GCMTokenHelper.java:79)
                                                            at com.amazonaws.mobile.push.PushManager.registerDevice(PushManager.java:196)
                                                            at com.intap.appme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
10-01 20:54:39.724 4725-4725/com.intap.appme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                           Process: com.intap.appme, PID: 4725
                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.intap.appme/com.intap.appme.MainActivity}: com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.InvalidParameterException: Invalid parameter: Endpoint (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: 698306d3-9079-53a0-8dc2-56ba6ae67d2b)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                            Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.InvalidParameterException: Invalid parameter: Endpoint (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: 698306d3-9079-53a0-8dc2-56ba6ae67d2b)
                                                               at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:712)
                                                               at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:388)
                                                               at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:199)
                                                               at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.invoke(AmazonSNSClient.java:2262)
                                                               at com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClient.subscribe(AmazonSNSClient.java:1256)
                                                               at com.amazonaws.mobile.push.PushManager.subscribeToTopic(PushManager.java:251)
                                                               at com.intap.appme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

The lines which are mentioned in the error log are those:
GCMTokenHelper.java:79

```
newDeviceToken = instanceID.getToken(gcmSenderID, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);
```

PushManager.java:196

```
gcmTokenHelper.updateGCMToken();
```

PushManager.java:251

```
final SubscribeResult result = sns.subscribe(request);
```

MainActivity.java:49

```
pushManager.registerDevice();
```

MainActivity.java:50

```
pushManager.subscribeToTopic(pushManager.getDefaultTopic());
```

I didn't really understand what's the problem in my code, so could you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't so intuitive that the error message just says `MAIN_THREAD` at the end without an explanation. That effectively indicates that the `pushManager.registerDevice()` method cannot be called from the main thread.

The Mobile Hub Sample App makes the call within an Async task. Here is an example.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(final Void... params) {
        // register device first to ensure we have a push endpoint.
        pushManager.registerDevice();

        // if registration succeeded.
        if (pushManager.isRegistered()) {
            if (pushManager.isPushEnabled()) {
                // if push is enabled, the push manager keeps its state
                // including the subscribed topics and automatically
                // re-subscribes when registering the device.
                return null;
            }
            try {
                // Enable push
                pushManager.setPushEnabled(true);
                // Automatically subscribe to the default SNS topic
                pushManager.subscribeToTopic(pushManager.getDefaultTopic());
                return null;
            } catch (final AmazonClientException ace) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Failed to change push notification status", ace);
                return ace.getMessage();
            }
        }

        return "Failed to register for push notifications.";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String errorMessage) {
        if (errorMessage != null) {
            // do something to show the error message...
        }
    }
}.execute();
```

Since you are currently calling `PushManager.registerDevice()` from your activity's `onCreate()` lifecycle method, you are calling it from the main thread, which isn't allowed. Switch to calling it in a background thread, such as using the `AsyncTask` example above and your problem should be resolved.